# A question on compound interest?

Tags: arithmetic

$10\%$ compounded quarterly, what is the equivalent rate of interest with monthly compounding?

Equivalent rate of interest$= (1+\frac{0.1}{3})^3 -1
=(1+0.033333)^3 -1
=0.1(nearly)
=10\%$

Is this solution correct? I am not sure.

Comment: You're looking to solve $1.1=(1+x)^3$?

Comment: Interest at rate $r$ compounded $n$ times a year normally means that you have $(1 + \frac{r}{n})^n$ times your initial deposit out the end of the year.  So technically, you want to solve $(1 + \frac{0.1}{4})^4 = (1 + \frac{r}{12})^{12}$ for $r$.  Unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 1):

The way compound interest rates are normally defined, an interest rate of $r$ compounded $n$ times per year means that after one year, you have $(1 + \frac{r}{n})^n$ times your original principal.  Thus,

$$(1 + \frac{0.1}{4})^4 = (1 + \frac{r}{12})^{12}$$
$$4 \log 1.025 = 12 \log (1 + \frac{r}{12})$$
$$\log (1 + \frac{r}{12}) = \frac{\log 1.025}{3}$$
$$1 + \frac{r}{12} \approx 1.0082648376090522$$
$$\frac{r}{12} \approx 0.0082648376090522$$
$$r \approx 0.099178051308626$$

So 10% interest compounded quarterly equates to approximately 9.92% interest compounded monthly.